# Exception when stopping JMS listeners programatically

Tags: java, spring-jms

I have written a JMS listener which starts when I start main class.

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "funMessageQ")
public void consumeMessageAsService(String message, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers)
    throws BusinessException {
    String jmsId = headers.get(JmsConstants.JMS_MESSAGE_ID).toString();
    String jmsCorrelationId = headers.get(JmsConstants.JMS_CORRELATION_ID).toString();
    log.info( "Message recieved  :" + message );
    try {
        messageProcessor.processMessage(message, headers);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error processing message");
    }
}
```

Then there is message processor

```java
public int processMessage(String message, Map<String, Object> messageHeader) {
    log.info(TraceLabelDelegate.SB_TVS_BA_INF0001, "Message recieved  :" + message );
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            log.info(TraceLabelDelegate.SB_TVS_BA_INF0001, "Do processing for message " + i );
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

While starting the main class I also check the status in database about this queue and we stop the listener when status is `TO_STOP` in the database.

```java
@Autowired
JmsListenerEndpointRegistry endPointRegistry;


@Order(2)
public CommandLineRunner stopActiveMqListnerCommand(ApplicationArguments arguments) {
    return a -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                boolean stopped = false;
                MqJobInfo jobInfo = mqService.findMqJobInfoByOrderId(jobName);
                if (jobInfo.getStatus().equals(STATUS_TO_STOP) || !jobInfo.getStatus().equals(STATUS_RUNNING)) {
                    endPointRegistry.stop();
                    endPointRegistry.destroy();
                    mqService.updateMqJobInfoToStopped(jobInfo);
                    stopped = true;
                }
                
                if (stopped) {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.sleep(pollingTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Now the problem is, when I change status `TO_STOP` and there is no active message processing then my listener is stopped and main class also stop.

But when we are processing some message in between, then I get below error -

```
[MessageProcessor,org.springframework.jms.JmsListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] [INFO1] Message recieved  :TEST MESSAGE . . . . . .
[MessageProcessor,org.springframework.jms.JmsListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] [INFO1] Do processing for message 0
[MessageProcessor,org.springframework.jms.JmsListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] [INFO1] Do processing for message 1
[MessageProcessor,org.springframework.jms.JmsListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] [INFO1] Do processing for message 2
[CRPRP--,1,config.SpringActiveMQConfig,main] [INFO1] Checking status for the mqtrigger job status, current status is :TO_STOP
[MessageProcessor,org.springframework.jms.JmsListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] [INFO1] Do processing for message 3
[MessageProcessor,org.springframework.jms.JmsListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] [INFO1] InterruptedException : 3
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at MessageProcessor.processMessage(MessageProcessor.java:27)
    at MessageConsumerPOC.consumeMessageAsService(MessageConsumerPOC.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77)
```

**I want to stop the listener but complete processing of the current message.**

Answer (score 0):

Don't `destroy()` the registry until your listener has completed its work, just stop it.

Comment: Thanks for reply,  even with only calling stop,
I am not able to call         . . .     Thread.sleep(1000);


"I get java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted"